# Hierarchy in ברכות השחר?

Tags: halacha, blessing, priorities

Of course there is a set order in the Siddur, but is there a hierarchy in ברכות השחר? If, for example, someone did not wash his hands or use the bathroom when he woke up, can he say Elokai Neshamah or ברכות התורה?

Answer (score 4):

One pair of brachot in the morning that must be said in order is Mattir Asurim before Zokef Kefufim. If one said Zokef Kefufim first, he no longer recites Mattir Asurim (Shulchan Aruch OC 46:5).

Some say the set of Shelo Asani X's must be said in order, and if one said a later one he can no longer say the previous ones. However the Mishna Berura who quotes this opinion (46 sk 16) tends to reject that position.

Some require Elohai Neshama to be lechatchila recited after another bracha because it doesn't itself start with "Baruch Attah...", but others reject this requirement (see OC 6:3 with commentaries). All agree this would not invalidate the bracha.

That's all I can think of in terms of *required* orderings. Different Nuschaot have different traditions for the rest of the order.

Answer (score 3):

To add to DoubleAA's answer:

The brachah of Ahavas Olam may exempt you from Birkas HaTorah. Therefore, you should say the latter first ([47:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=148)). The brachah of Mechayah HaMeisim may exempt you from Elokai Neshamah ([MB 6:12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=24)). DoubleAA wrote in [his answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18429/1569) that some say that you have to say Elokai Neshamah after Asher Yatzar; the [Rama](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=146) says to say Birchos HaTorah immediately after it. The korbanos have a specific order, as explained in [1:5-8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=9) (and see Aruch HaShulchan there for the explanation of the Ashkenazi practice of saying only three things). I thought I remembered seeing in the Mishnah Brurah that you can say the brachos even if you don't experience the things (e.g. hearing an actual rooster crow), but I can't find it.

Comment: I specifically avoided your first two issues because he asked about a hierarchy in _Birkot Hashachar_ not regarding the whole siddur. Your third point is explicitly a matter of custom as the Rama mentions. Your last point is discussed in [46:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95) but it's missing from the pdf you linked to.

Comment: @DoubleAA 1. I thought it would count because it deals with Birkas HaTorah and Elokai Neshamah, both of which are birkos hashachar. 2. Of course; I just added that part because your answer quoted a source in an earlier siman which the Rama didn't say that.

Comment: Also, if you already said Shema later in davening, you wouldn't have to go back and say *Le'olam yehei adam yerei shamayim*.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Can you source that?

Comment: @DoubleAA - How is that any different?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Are you trying to say that the only reason we say Leolam, etc. is because of the Shema included in it? That doesn't seem true, because if so, all we would need to do is say the first pasuk of Shema. Furthermore, why would be say the paragraph of "Atah hu..." after it?

Comment: @AdamMosheh Just to boost ba's point, there is a unique bracha at the end of the paragraph (at least in some nuschaot). For them, they should still have to say the bracha even after reciting shema.

Comment: @DoubleAA - *Tzarikh iyyun*.